# How can I jump to a given year on the Google Calendar application on my Google Pixel 6 phone?

Tags: android-12, google-calendar, google-pixel-6, history

I  use the Google Calendar application on my Google Pixel 6 phone. Sometimes I want to look at some event a few years ago. How can I jump to a given year on Google calendar?

Comment: On the web, you can press the `g` key to go to a particular date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Google support [How to navigate to a specific date in google calendar Android app. E.g going to Aug-14&seeing events](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/15810710/how-to-navigate-to-a-specific-date-in-google-calendar-android-app-e-g-going-to-aug-14-seeing-events?hl=en)

> ... there's no way to do this in the Android app, but you can ask Google Assistant to list events from a given month or date. For example : "OK Google, show my events in August this year", then click on a result to open that event.

I didn't fully verify this as I don't use Google assistant but by invoking it on long press of <kbd>home</kbd>, and keying in as advised, I could see events upto two years ago.

Comment: The fact that the android app doesn't allow this is so stupid. It would be so easy to implement a picker that you could show tapping on the top bar to select a date and move the calendar to that date, like the material date picker.

Comment: This is not an answer the question, since that is app specific. However a 3rd party app like aCalendar (which is just another frontend for google calendar) offers years to pick from the hamburger menu, which might be quicker for selecting a specific year than an assistant. Maybe it is worth taking a look at this or other such apps.